# Is one commonly "on a desert" or in it?

Tags: meaning

> There was nothing to see. He was in the middle of a desert. No wonder he was so thirsty. But, luckily, he had brought his purple crayon. And he knew where to find water on a desert

In my experience, common usage finds one "in a desert" rather than "on" one. Honestly, this is my first time encountering this particular usage anywhere.

Is it more common to say (verbally or in writing) that one is "in a desert" or "on a desert"? Has common usage of this phrase shifted since the book's original copyright date in 1957 or are there other reasons for this difference in usage? I have already seen other questions similar to this one such as "On a page" or "in a page" for a web page and I understand that prepositions are used interchangeably in some situations. My question is not about correct usage but common usage. Any examples from other written works would be appreciated I have this U.S. perspective to contribute: I was editing a book in which a character pulled her car "Onto to the driveway" and later "Onto the parking lot." I changed it to Into. But the author argued that they say "into" in Pennsylvania(I'm in Illinois). She claims that the driveway is the pavement, so of course you are on/above it. I think the driveway is the international airspace above the pavement, so you are IN it.

Comment: As you suspect, "in a desert" is vastly more common than "on a desert" (which I don't think I've ever heard).

Comment: I wonder if you have the context wrong.  If having a purple crayon can solve his water problem then he must be on a *drawing* of a desert.

Comment: This is from one of the *Harold and his Purple Crayon* children's books. I believe the author is referring to the fact that Harold is standing on a purple line that he drew, and is dreaming is a desert. (Please note that Harold was not able to draw a balloon to fly or a window to crawl through.)

Comment: *In* is used of most spaces: *in a desert*, *in a veldt*, *in a park*, *in a garden*, *in a field*, except sometimes where something is flat and laid out according to a design - *on a parade ground*, *on a tennis court*. Note that *on a road* or *in a road* are both common but have slightly different contexts (*driving on a road*, *standing in a road*).

Comment: @Hot Licks He doesn't need une pipe then.